# Need AppleScript to ignore extra line in TAB input file

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to read in a tab delimited file that was exported from Filemaker Pro. Filemaker adds an extra return or line feed at the end of every export. I can't get my AppleScript to ignore this extra line. I'm new to AppleScript and could use some help.

Here's the section of code where I tried to ignore the line with the if statement -- not working.

```
-- read the file into a list based on paragraph delimiters (e.g. one path per line)
set fileList to (paragraphs of (read file theInputFile))
-- iterate through the file list
repeat with eachFilePath in fileList
    if eachFilePath ≠ "" then -- there's something there...
        -- build the path to the current file
        set inFile to POSIX file (pathPrefix & eachFilePath as text)
        tell application "Finder"
            try
                if exists file inFile then
                    duplicate inFile to folder outFolder with replacing and exact copy
                end if
            on error
                --      something went wrong, so record the missed file
                copy eachFilePath to end of errorList
                log " missing file " & errorList
            end try
        end tell
    end if
end repeat

-- the code then continues to produce a text file with all the missing files.
```

Here's a link to testing input file on Dropbox you should be able to download it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vsbpat76f9hqpk6/Testing%20Input.tab?dl=0

Comment: It's way easier to answer code-level questions if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and an example of the input data to be processed.

Comment: I can attach a small tab file I use for testing but don't know how to attach it to his post

Comment: A link also works, but this alone doesn't make the code work as such. The main guess currently is that the last line is not empty but let's see. Also, you talk about tab-delimited but nothing in your code handles tabs.

Comment: Upload the file to Google Drive, etc., make it viewable/downloadable by anyone with its link and update your post to include the link.

Comment: the file only contains a single field for each record so there is no real need to look for tab delimiters. It is used to create a path to folders on a network drive.

Comment: Don't read the file as paragraphs. Just read the whole thing and then set a var to `text 1 thru -2 of wholeText`. Then `set fileList to paragraphs of wholeText`.

Comment: where does the var get used. I'm really new at this

Comment: Thank you Mockman - I figured out what you were telling me and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

The first method inhales the text as paragraphs into a list and then sheds the last item. The second method reads the entire text and grabs every character but the final one (i.e. the extraneous linefeed) and then makes a list of paragraphs.

**Update:** Added if…then to test for whether input file ends with a blank line.

**Method 1**

```
use scripting additions
-- two test files, one ends with linefeed
set theInputFile to "MacHD:Users:username:fmempty.txt"
-- set theInputFile to "MacHD:Users:username:fmtext.txt"

set readFile to (get paragraphs of (read file theInputFile))
if last item of readFile is "" then
    set lastPara to -2
else
    set lastPara to -1
end if

set fileList to items 1 thru lastPara of readFile
repeat with eachFilePath in fileList
[…]
```

**Method 2**

```
use scripting additions
-- two test files, one ends with linefeed
set theInputFile to "MacHD:Users:username:fmempty.txt"
-- set theInputFile to "MacHD:Users:username:fmtext.txt"

set readFile to (read file theInputFile)
if last character of readFile is linefeed then
    set fileText to text 1 thru -2 of readFile
else
    set fileText to text of readFile
end if

set fileList to paragraphs of fileText
repeat with eachFilePath in fileList
[…]
```

NB the `read` command is part of the Standard Additions, hence the opening `use scripting additions` line.

Comment: So, if at some point Filemaker does not add the extra linefeed would Method 1 remove the last entry which would than be valid?

Comment: It would remove the last paragraph. If filemaker does not add a linefeed, then it would remove whatever last paragraph is there. You could put that in an if…then statement that asks if the last paragraph is "" then….

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your "Testing Input.tab" to my downloads folder.  That said, to avoid having to use conditional loops to check for empty paragraphs... My approach was to simply remove any empty paragraphs right off the bat using the `do shell script` command and set the `fileList` variable to that result.

```
set theInputFile to POSIX path of ¬
    ((path to downloads folder as text) & "Testing Input.tab")

set fileList to paragraphs of ¬
    (do shell script "cat " & quoted form of theInputFile & " |sed '/^$/d'")

repeat with eachFilePath in fileList
    --process eachFilePath
    delay 0.1
end repeat
```

**Option 2:** In my opinion this following solution is probably the easiest to understand and troubleshoot if necessary.(For those who are new to **AppleScript**)

```
set fileList to paragraphs of (read theInputFile)

if last item of fileList = "" then set fileList to reverse of ¬
    rest of reverse of paragraphs of (read theInputFile)

repeat with eachFilePath in fileList
    -- set inFile to POSIX file (pathPrefix & eachFilePath as text)
    tell application "Finder"
        
    end tell
end repeat
```

---

**Update:** After having one of those "I can't believe I did not think of this sooner" moments, I realize this following solution is the quickest way to remove the empty last line (if it exists), from the results of the `paragraphs of read` command.  The solution is not using the `paragraphs of`, but to use the `read` command with `using delimiter return as text` instead.

```
set theInputFile to ((path to downloads folder as text) & "Testing Input.tab")

set fileList to read alias theInputFile using delimiter return as text

set fileNames to {} -- for example command

repeat with filePath in fileList -- example command to perform on each path
    set end of fileNames to (do shell script "basename " & filePath)
end repeat
```

Comment: Being new to scripting and not understanding shell scripts at all I've tested Method 2 from @Mockman and it does exactly what is needed. If Filemaker ever stops putting an extra linefeed, Method 2 will just keep on working without deleting the last char of the last record.  PERFECT!

Comment: @JBS  I updated my post and added a second option, which you may be interested in.

Comment: @wch1zpink sed can access files directly so you can dispense with using 'cat'. Try `set fileList to paragraphs of (do shell script "sed '/^$/d' < " & quoted form of theInputFile)`. Actually, I think you can even remove the `<` and it will still work.